# Nuxt middlewares does not work when page reloaded

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I added middlewares to default.vue component:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    TheHeader
  },
  middleware: ['auth'],
}
```

My auth.js:

```js
export default function ({ app, store }) {
  if (app.$cookies.get('AUTH_TOKEN')) {
    var AUTH_TOKEN = app.$cookies.get('AUTH_TOKEN')
    app.$axios.$post('https://example.com/api', {
      email: Buffer.from(AUTH_TOKEN[0], 'base64').toString(),
      password: Buffer.from(AUTH_TOKEN[1], 'base64').toString(),
    }).then(response => {
      store.dispatch('changeAuthStatus', {
        authStatus: true,
        userData: {
          id: response.data.id,
          login: response.data.login,
          email: response.data.email,
          firstName: response.data.first_name,
          lastName: response.data.last_name,
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

So I can't understand why my middlewares don't load when the page is reloaded or with direct access to the page. Also `mode: 'universal'` and `ssr: true` are set in `nuxt.config.js`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, because I need to check auth token before the page loaded. So I think that I need to add it to the default.vue file in layouts pages.

Comment: What is not working? It should be good. Double check that your code is properly reached. You could also try to `await axios.get` a JSON placeholder URL and throttle your internet bandwidth (network tab in devtools) to see it taking several seconds to resolve and then proceed navigating or loading your page. You could even use a sleep method like this: `await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 7000))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the middlewares: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/

Few steps to have a working middleware:

- use it **only** in a page (`/pages/hello.vue`) or layout (`/layouts/MyFancyLayout.vue`)
- put the middleware in the proper directory (`/middleware/test.js`)
- call it properly in the `.vue` file like `middleware: 'test'`

You can also try to debug and see if something like this works

```js
export default {
  middleware() {
    console.log('working!')
  }
}
```

It is working on client transitions and should be good on initial page load aswell.

Answer (score -1):

As a more accurate way, you should do this in the Vuex Store using the 'context' attribute.

middleware/auth.js

```
export default function(context) {

if (process.client) {
    context.store.dispatch('initAuth', null);
}
context.store.dispatch('initAuth', context.req);

}
```

store/index.js

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'
```

store/index.js

```
            actions:{
              initAuth(vuexContext,state){
            let token;
            let jwtCookie;
            

            if (req) {
                if (!req.headers.cookie) {
                    return;
                }
                jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie
                    .split(";")
                    .find(c => c.trim().startsWith("jwt="));
                if (!jwtCookie) {
                    return;
                }
                token = jwtCookie.split('=')[1];
                
            } else {
                token = localStorage.getItem('token');
               

            }
            vuexContext.commit('setToken', token);
            return $axios.post('https://example.com/api', {
            email: Buffer.from(AUTH_TOKEN[0], 'base64').toString(),
            password: Buffer.from(AUTH_TOKEN[1], 'base64').toString(),
            }).then(response => {
            vuexContext.commit('changeAuthStatus', {
            authStatus: true,
            userData: {
            id: response.data.id,
            login: response.data.login,
            email: response.data.email,
            firstName: response.data.first_name,
            lastName: response.data.last_name,
            }
          })
       })
      }
     }
```

this way it will work smoothly and understandably